# [Vue warn]: Property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. ("content")...etc

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

**My view page code**

```
<div id="app">
@{{ msg }}
@{{ content }}
```

**using form here**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="addPost">
                      <textarea v-model="content" id="postText" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" id="postBtn">Post</button>
            </form></div>
```

**This is my app.js code**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
```

**returing data here**
        data: {
            return:{
             msg: 'Make Post:',
            content: '',
            bUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/pathikhome',
        }
        },
        methods: {
**getting addpost data**

```
        addPost(){
            axios.post(this.bUrl +'/addPost', {
                content: this.content
            })
                .then( (response) =>{
                    this.content="";
                    console.log('saved successfully'); // show if success
                    if(response.status===200){
                        app.posts = response.data;
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error); // run if we have error
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After loading the data you're doing `app.posts = response.data`. What is `app`?!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    data: {
        msg: 'Make Post:',
       content: '',
       bUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/pathikhome',
     },
```

Instead of you code:

```
  data: {
     return:{
        msg: 'Make Post:',
      content: '',
      bUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/pathikhome',
     }
   },
```

Because in your code you are trying return an object from an object.

Comment: why dont you show us your view page and your app.js file more clearly, you have only shown parts of them and is hard for us to debug

Comment: when i am trying to modify the code here then seeing some error ..add some context something like this..i hope now much clearer

Comment: i am seeing the same data return thing in your code still